# Loss of power with power tools

Tags: electrical

Working on my mothers house.  When using a power tool the electrical power drops.  I don’t have enough power to cut a board or tile. No breakers or GFCI are being tripped. Where is my power going?  No one currently resides at home and lights are the only thing drawing power except tools when used.  Lights also dim when power tools are turned on.  Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: I imagine these are DIY power tools and not big woodshop tools.  It sounds like very bad loose electrical connections or lost of neutral or hot power line.  Have power company come out to check their wires.  If not them you will need an electrician.

Comment: Just to emphasize @crip659 comment: That seems **quite unsafe**.  To see if it's a lost neutral, turn on lamps in many rooms, start up the power tool, and note if some get **brighter** when the tool is **on**. In any case, high circuit resistance could lead to fire, and bad neutral to fire *and* destruction of appliances and electric shock.

Comment: Is this true for all outlets on all circuits or just one? If for all then there is some issue with the power coming into the house or inside the electrical panel. If it's just one outlet then there is a loose connection in some junction box; installing an AFCI breaker would let you know if  a specific circuit is arcing. Any of the aforementioned scenarios are quite dangerous so get a competent electrician to check things out and use battery-powered tools in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a Lost Neutral from the utility.  I would start by searching the overhead drop wires.  It is triplex wire with the neutral being carried on the bare wire (which also physically carries the weight of all the wires).  If you see a gap in the bare wire, and the works hanging by the 2 insulated conductors, that's the definition of a lost neutral.

For an illustration of what's happening there, see [this brilliant Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg).

The reason voltage weakens instead of going away, is that neutral has an alternate path - via the service neutral-ground bond to the ground rods, to the dirt, to another house's ground rods and back via their neutral-ground bond.

95% of the time the problem is on the utility side with their service drop wires. They will fix this for free.